# Auto-correlation of a linear model in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to tackle auto-correlation on data for my BSc honours project but this is my first time, and I could really use some advice.

I am trying to model mean monthly species abundance and mean monthly sea surface temperature (SST) over a period of 12 years using;

```
    modelw<-lm(SPECIES~SST,
           data=dat, na.action=na.exclude)
summary(modelw)
```

I have the residuals and ACF

[Modelw residuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHvOZ.jpg)

[Modelw ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJeln.jpg)

I can see there is autocorrelation, so I have tried to fix using the following;

```
> library(nlme)
    modelw2 <- gls(SPECIES ~SST, data=dat, 
                  correlation = corAR1(form=~SPECIES),
                  na.action=na.omit)
    summary(modelw2)
```

This hasn't worked because (I think) it is supposed to be used if one of the variables are dates? Could someone please point me in the right direction of a script I could try that will work with mean abundance and SST?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Asked too soon, I worked it out! :)

Comment: You can answer your own question with the solution you found (for future viewers)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the corrected script;

```
library(nlme)
modelw2 <- gls(SPECIES ~SST, data=dat, 
               correlation = corAR1(form=~MONTH),
               na.action=na.omit)
summary(modelw2)
```

`form` should have been the column containing the date.